# Terrain detection on racing game

Tags: java, libgdx, racing

Hi I don't speak English very well so ill try to do my best :P

I'm doing my first top-down racing game for LibGDX, now I need to create tracks, the tracks aren't very large, I prefer doing this with a set of tiles with different types of curves, because I want to do a level editor.
So I need to check whether the car is on the track or not. I thought that these alternatives are good but I need help by choosing the best one

- An big array. Doing an array of tiles, saving whether in that position there is a track, looks very memory consupting
- A set of polygons. And then checking if the car is inside them. Looks very CPU consupting
- An Black-White image of the track. I've seen a recomendation here about that, but looks similar to an array

Do you know another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to say the array. Creating a black and white image, then processing it based on color can really limit gameplay. It also creates a lot of lag(assuming you're using java's robot), Polygons may work, but wouldn't that be like a more complicated version of an array? I see no real advantage to polygons. UNLESS... You have really weird and irregularly shaped bounds, such as triangles and hexagons used together.

Comment: I agree with dylan, And just because it is a big array doesn't mean it will be laggy... You could make it so that it only renders tiles within a certain distance... e.g. Have it only render the tiles that are inside your window. Of course you may have to extend it by a few so there aren't any black spots whilst rendering the next tiles... If you want i can create a youtube video for you demonstrating this method?? This is the method i have used for a 700 * 700 map of 32pixel tiles and I get no lag from the map rendering at all...

Comment: Oh perfect, Ill do that. Thanks for the fast answer! :D

Comment: glad to hear it helped you.